# Bash not recognizing .pid file

Tags: bash, bamboo

I have a process pid stored in a file 'app.pid'. But my below bash script executed from Bamboo, doesn't find the file. I have verified multiple times that the file 'app.pid' is present.

```
#!/bin/bash
pidFile=$1

echo $pidFile
pid=$(<"$pidFile")
if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
    echo "Pid not found!"
else
    echo "Pid exists! killing lookup service!!"
    kill $pid
fi
```

Comment: Try giving full path for pid file? `Bamboo` may have started your script from a different directory?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
[xyz@kuthu bin]$ ./app.pid
bash: ./app.pid: Permission denied
```

Shows you're trying to execute the PID file itself.  You should instead be running your script with `app.pid` as an argument.

Comment: Yes, those two outputs of file, and ./app.pid - I just wanted to share. But the script I give the pid file path as input

Comment: If `cat` doesn't work, you have a serious problem.  As in, the file does not actually exist, if `cat` says it does not exist.  You haven't posted enough info here to know what's wrong, but it's something about the path you're using.

Comment: cat does works from the shell, but not when executed from Bamboo.

Comment: Are you `cat`ing an absolute path, or a relative one?  If your path doesn't start with `/` (i.e. it's relative), you probably are not in the directory you think you are in.